# Invalid IL code in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider:.ctor (System.Type): method body is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mono

I am deploying an MVC3 project to a Mono linux box.  I had the skeleton working pretty nice, but when I started filling in some models, views, and controllers, I got the error you see above.

There does not seem to be much documentation on this; what little I've seen suggests that it cannot find my `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` file, but I've set the dll to copy local and added it to the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` folder, with no success.

It seems like I'm missing something simple.  Any guesses what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem goes away if I do NOT include the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` file when publishing.